# How to add ssl certificate in grails server?

Tags: grails, ssl

I have ssl .crt and key files. How to add it to grails server. Grails is using a keystore file by default. How to add the cert files from a CA authority? The server is started using `grails run-app -https`.

Comment: Do you have an SSL directory? (inside the grail's project?)

Comment: The ssl directory is under `.grails\2.0.3\projects\<appName>\ssl`. Which contains a keystore file.

Comment: what server are you running?

Comment: Server is development grails server ran using `grails run-app -https`.